# How is the parameter space of $U(1)$ same as $\mathbb{S}^1$?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics

An U(1) group element can be parameterized as $g=\exp(ic\xi)$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. In physics textbooks, I have found that the parameter space of $U(1)$ is referred to as $\mathbb{S}^1$. However, I have the following three questions regarding this.

**1**. How do I show that the parameter space of $\xi$ defines a circle? I mean why not $0\leq \xi<4\pi$ or even $-\infty<\xi<+\infty$? What forbids such values for $\xi$?

**2**. Even if $\xi$ is restricted to $0\leq \xi<2\pi$, does it necessarily define a circle? I mean, on any closed path on a plane $\xi$ is restricted to $0\leq \xi<2\pi$. Isn't it?

**3**. Is it necessarily a unit circle? If yes, what indicates that?

Comment: What is your definition of $\Bbb S^1$? It's convenient to think of it as the unit circle in $\Bbb C$, which readily answers all of your questions. (Regardless of your definition, the key observation is that the mapping $\xi \mapsto g$ is periodic.)

Comment: We should simply take $g = \exp(i \xi)$, noting that the "arbitrary constant" is redundant if we absorb it into our parameter.  Also, recall Euler's formula:
$$
exp(i\xi) = \cos(\xi) + i \sin (\xi)
$$
This tells us that $\exp(i \xi)$ is necessarily a point on the unit circle (i.e. the point $(\cos \xi, \sin \xi)$ in $2D$ space).

Comment: If you take $g=\exp(ic\xi)$ and $0 \leq \xi < 4\pi$ then you will cover $U(1)$ twice. You could of course instead take $g=\exp(ic\xi/2)$ and get away from that, but *topologically* the parameter space is still $S^1$.

Comment: I want to emphasize that the parameter space is $S^1$ *topologically*, not necessarily geometrically.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "the parameter space of $U(1)$" is ambiguous to me. I would be suspicious of that phrase without a proper mathematical definition.

Certainly it does **not** mean the space of $\xi$ values, as your guesses in items 1 and 2 seem to assume.

If you wanted to assign a letter variable as a "parameter", then you could assign a dependent variable to the expression $\text{exp}(i c \xi)$, say 
$$z = \text{exp}(i c \xi))
$$
Then you could observe that the set of values of $z$ --- the "image" of the function $\text{exp}(i c \xi)$ --- is indeed $\mathbb{S}^1$ which is the unit circle in the complex plane. That does give you a reasonable mathematical notion of what it means to say "the parameter space of $U(1)$ is $\mathbb{S}^1$".

Here's some important features to notice, in order to understand why $\xi$ itself is a bad parameter for the whole of $U(1)$.

First, the function $z = \text{exp}(i c \xi))$ is not one-to-one, in fact it is infinite-to-one, because of the periodicity of the exponential function. This is bad if what you want is a one-to-one global parameter.

You could also try to restrict to various $\xi$ subintervals, for instance $0 \le \xi \le \frac{2\pi}{c}$, and then the restricted function is almost but not quite one-to-one, because the endpoints $0$ and $\frac{2\pi}{c}$ have the same image.

You could repair the endpoint problem by restricting $\xi$ to the half open interval $0 \le \xi < \frac{2\pi}{c}$. Now you get a one-to-one and onto function from this half-open interval to $U(1)$. However this creates a topological problem, because that function has discontinuous inverse, and so is not a homeomorphism.

So, if you care about having a parameter which represents each point of $U(1)$ in a one-to-one fashion, and if you care that your parameter represent $U(1)$ with the correct topology --- that is, by a homeomorphism --- then there's really no way to repair this so that the independent variable $\xi$ is a good parameter for $U(1)$. You *have* to use a dependent variable like $z$.

Comment: When physicists talk about the parameter space of the group SU(2), they mean the space of the parameters (which is $\mathbb{S}^3$) of a most generally parameterized $U$ matrix $U\in SU(2)$. This is why I thought the space of $\xi$ should be $\mathbb{S}^1$. Thanks @LeeMosher